# Deploying a Tensorflow/Keras model in Spark Pipeline

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have trained several `RNN+biLSTM` models that I want to deploy in a pipeline consisting of `pyspark` pipeline steps. `spark-deep-learning` seems to be a stale project that only accommodates work with image data. Are there any best practices today for loading `tensorflow`/`keras` models (and their associated vector embeddings) into `pyspark` pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy a tensorflow model into Spark, you should take a look at [Deeplearning4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/). It comes with some Importers, where you can read [keras](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/keras-import-overview) and [TensorFlow](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/tf-import) models. 
Be aware, that not every layer is supported.

Besides spark-deep-learning there is [tensorframe](https://github.com/databricks/tensorframes), i never used it , so I don´t know how good it is.

In general I would suggest to use tensorflow directly via [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) and not using all these wrappers.